# How can I design two CMOS ring oscillators so that I can observe sub harmonic injection locking?

Tags: oscillator, cmos

I am trying to design two CMOS ring oscillators for the purpose of observing sub harmonic injection locking. I want the injection frequency to be two times the locking frequency. I have designed some simple ring oscillators. The design is mostly like below except that there is a capacitor after each oscillator inverter stage:
[image: circuit diagram that I have followed]

I feel that the locking effect is not taking place. I can't make any conclusion based on observing the output waveforms.

I also want to observe the phase binarising effect.

1. What factors do I have to keep in mind to design the oscillators? Is
   there any better design than the one I have provided above?
2. How can I connect the oscillators?
3. Is there any article where specific design techniques are provided?
   Please provide the            links if you know of some.
4. Is cadence virtuoso or SPICE based simulators like HSPICE suitable for observing this
   effect? Is there any better alternative?

Thanks in advance!